# Function to add line breaks to a string every so many characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5

I need a temp work around for a script that only has 1 possible styling.     Is there a simple way to loop through a string and add line breaks? Like at every 80th character insert a '\n'?   (really looping through a record set and doing this to a text field).

Thanks!

Comment: Rails has the word_wrap method in the TextHelper module, you can use it your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another approach:

```
"hello".scan(/.{1}/).join("\n")
```

Comment: If the string length is not a multiple of the "slice" length, the last shorter segment will not be included. Instead, specify a minimum. For the OP this would be `"hello".scan(/.{1,10}/).join("\n")`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is the best approach.. but you could use each_slice here. Maybe something like:

```
"SOME AWESOME STRING".chars.each_slice(80).map(&:join).join('\n')
```

Comment: Thanks - Rails and IRB didn't like that at all :p

Comment: I'll work up a regex for this.. looking at this now.. i dont like it